# how do i fix ValueError: number of input channels does not match corresponding dimension of filter, 3 != 64

Tags: python, machine-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am almost 100% sure this is the code that is making life tough on me right now:

```
model.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(3, 64, 64), border_mode = 'same'))
```

sorry for the short description but I don't know what to do here, I am very new to GANs, and machine learning overall.

Comment: input shape would be `(64, 64, 3)`

Comment: like i said i am VERY new to this, but thanks xD

Comment: I mean input_shape should be `(row, col, number_of_channel)`.

Comment: okay thank you, great for future reference!

Comment: If your input to a layer is `(n, m, k_in)` and you apply `k_out` filters  with `border_mode = same` then  then your output shape will be `(n, m, k_out)`. You can see that channel is the last dimension.

Answer (score 1):

@Amit Vikram Singh's answer is valid and I'd further like to add that you should have it in a `try/except` code block so your program won't crash if it runs into a similar error. You can use something like this:

```
try:
    model.add(Convolution2D(128, 5, 5, subsample=(2, 2), input_shape=(64, 64, 3), border_mode = 'same'))
except ValueError:
    # code to run if it fails here
```

Comment: Thank you, got that specific part to work but this is great for future problems :)